# Nginx handling Domain Name Forwarding to tomcat

Tags: apache, redirect, nginx, reverse-proxy, self-hosting

I have domain name http://xyzabc.com and I am hosting few sample apps at my local machine

Since My ISP **blocks port 80**, So I have to forward my domain name to Port 81; So I Defined the Forwarding (http://xx.xx.xx.xx:81) in godaddy and I configured 2 subdomains foo.xyzabc.com and bar.xyzabc.com and Used forwarding as (http://xx.xx.xx.xx:81) and (http://xx.xx.xx.xx:81) Respectively.

At my Router I defined port forwarding to map external port 81 to internal port 80, at which **nginx is Running**.

Until this point every thing is working http://xyzabc.com, http://foo.xyzabc.com with my main website content.

Now I want to map **tomcat** when somebody type http://foo.xyzabc.com to http://localhost:8080/ And I am confused how to configure that.

What I tried is :

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name foo.xyzabc.com
location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 81;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_redirect http://xx.xx.xx.xx:81/ http://localhost:8080/;
}
```

}

And

```
    location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_connect_timeout 150;
    proxy_send_timeout 100;
            proxy_read_timeout 100;
}
```

And **many Permutation combination** but I am not able to get the Tomcat webpage when typing http://foo.xyzabc.com/

I will really appreciate any help in this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the `server_name` parameter in your `server` block?

e.g:

```
server {
    listen 80
    server_name foo.xyzabc.com;

    location / {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I did that too

Comment: Can you post the output of your access_log and error_log for a single request?

Comment: Sure... I will paste in once I will revert the Settings, But For a Temp solution what is Did is I made one more "forward" from godaddy itself. So When somebody will type  http://foo.xyzabc.com in the browser it will actually redirect me to tomcat.  But I tried many "Correct" combination through nginx and Was not able to get that.  I will post the logs later. Thank